# why for loop is giving me errors in JSON parsed objects?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop a JSON response from my Web API but it has some unexpected behaviors.
The below function is working fine :

```
  insertListUser(data:any){
    console.log(data);
    this.service.uploadRecords(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      let resArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).body;
      console.log(resArray);
      // resArray.forEach((element:any) => {
      //   console.log(element);
      // });
    });
  }
```

[image: console log for var resArray]
But when I try to loop through the Response Array by uncommenting the foreach loop and checking the res var:

```
  insertListUser(data:any){
    console.log(data);
    this.service.uploadRecords(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      let resArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).body;
      console.log(resArray);
      resArray.forEach((element:any) => {
        console.log(element);
      });
    });
  }
```

Its console log is this:
[image: console log of res var]

EDIT: While someone asked for a response without foreach loop:
[image: res var log]

I wanted to add more things I have tried, so this works but result cannot be understood:

```
  insertListUser(data:any){
    console.log(data);
    let l=data.length;
    this.service.uploadRecords(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      let resArray=(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).body);
      console.log(resArray+" = "+l);
      for(let i in resArray){
        console.log(i);
      }
    });
  }
```

result:
[image: starting...]
[image: ...ending]
but when tried this (see the change in for loop):

```
  insertListUser(data:any){
    console.log(data);
    let l=data.length;
    this.service.uploadRecords(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      let resArray=(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).body);
      console.log(resArray+" = "+l);
      for(let i of resArray){
        console.log(i);
      }
    });
  }
```

and the results are:
[image: The same thing again :(]

Comment: Can you provide the response data in JSON format to the question? Thanks.

Comment: if `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(` is really working u can just ommit that part, means u already get json returned, can u maybe add a sample of the response data `res.body `?

Comment: is your posted response from console.log(data); or console.log(resArray)?

Comment: line 56 is console.log(res); and line 58 is console.log(resArray);

Comment: try `let resArray = JSON.parse(res.body);`

Comment: Dinh Carabus throws "type 0" in console log

Comment: john smith It's not working, gives "type 0" in the console log.

Comment: It looks like `response.body` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @BizzyBob as you can see in the picture that is in the picture has a response and inside response, there's a body too. the body can be accessed but whenever trying to use some prebuilt function in it gives an error????

Comment: Yes, response has body property,  but response.body is not a valid JSON string, so it doesn't get parsed as an array; so you cannot use `.forEach`.  `[\"Line 1..."]` is invalid.  `["Line 1..."]` is valid.  The `\` is messing it up.

Comment: @BizzyBob so what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Change the server to return valid json response.

Comment: @BizzyBob I also did change the response to a single String but ended with the same output, normally I can console.log and see the response and response.body but if I use split function in becomes type ZERO. Why the above lines are impacting if use a function to this variable below??? WHAT IS THIS "type 0"??